# JAVA Вызов конструктора из метода

Tags: java, методы, конструктор

Пишу программу, где требуется вызвать создание окна в конструкторе из метода `main`. Код:

```
    private class window extends JFrame
{
        public window()
        {
            setTitle("Спасибо!");
            setSize(500, 300);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Вызов конструктора window */
    }
}
```

Вопрос, собственно в том, что надо писать на месте комментария, чтобы при вызове метода создалось окно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите метод `main` как `static`

```
import javax.swing.*;

class window extends JFrame {
    public static void main() {
        new window();
    }
    void construct() {
        setTitle("Hello");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public window() {
        construct();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window.main();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, мне не понятно что у вас в теле метода?

Comment: Объявление переменной `w`

Comment: а для чего она в данном случае? мне надо только конструктор вызвать

Comment: Можно просто `new window()`. Переменная нужна, если планируется изменение параметров либо передача в другие функции.

Comment: я немного не про то. Когда я вызываю метод должны выполнится действия в конструкторе, как это сделать?

Comment: Что то я запутался. Дополните вопрос примером вызова.

Comment: import javax.swing.*;
public class test {
    public statick void main(String[] args){
        window.main();
    }
    publick class window extends JFrame {
        public window() {
            setTitle("123");
            setSize(100, 100);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(){
            //Вызов конструктора window
        }
    }
}

Comment: Исправил ответ.